# How to match the main subgroup in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, preg-match

Having this string:

```
"example( other(1), 123, [25]).othermethod(456)"
```

How i can capture only the arguments of the main functions:

```
"other(1), 123, [25]" and "456"
```

I am trying this:
http://regex101.com/r/cR0uS9/2

In html example. Having this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>12</div>
        <div>34</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>56</div>
```

I want to get:

```
<div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>34</div>
</div>
```

and `56` as second match.

Comment: post some more examples.

Comment: your previous and current questions are totally different.

Comment: This is not something that should be done with regex. (I'll try to come up with a pattern nevertheless.)

Comment: in what language do you want to implement this? if you are looking for a pure regular expression, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pattern that doesn't use recursion:

```
\w+\s*\((?P<parameters>(?:(?:(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))+|[^()]*)(?:,(?!\s*\))|(?=\))))*)\)
```

Caveats:

1. Does not support more than 2 levels of nested braces. e.g.
   `a(b(c()))`
2. Strings containing `(` or `)` will trip it up. e.g.
   `a(")")`

You'll find the parameters in the group called "parameters".

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/qI3yN2/2)

Explanation:

```
\w+ # function name
\s* # white space
\(
(?P<parameters> # parameters:
    (?:
        # two possibilities:    1: a simple parameter, like "12", "'hello'", or "3*1+2"
        #                       2: the parameter contains braces.
        # we'll try to consume pairs of braces. If that fails, we'll simply match a parameter.
        (?:
            (?: # match a pair of braces ()
                [^()]*
                \(
                [^()]*
                \)
            )+ # consume as many pairs of braces as possible. Make sure there's at least one, though, because we can't go matching nothing.
        |
            [^()]* # since there are no more (pairs of) braces, simply consume the function's parameters.
        )

        # next, either consume a "," or assert there's a ")"
        (?:
            ,
            (?! # make sure there is another parameter after the comma
                \s*
                \)
            )
        |
            (?=
                \)
            )
        )
    )*
)
\)
```

P.S.: I haven't managed to come up with an acceptable pattern for the HTML example yet.

Answer (score 0):

This does some recursion. Use it in a global find function.

```
 # '~(?is)(?:([a-z]\w*)\s*\(((?&core)|)\))(?(DEFINE)(?<core>(?>(?&content)|(?:[a-z]\w*\s*\(|\()(?:(?=.)(?&core)|)\))+)(?<content>(?>(?![a-z]\w*\s*\(|[()]).)+))~'

 (?xis-)
 (?:
      ( [a-z] \w* )         # (1), Start-Delimiter, Function
      \s* \(                   
      (                     # (2), CORE
           (?&core) 
        |  
      )
      \)                    # End-Delimiter, close paren
 )

 # ///////////////////////
 # // Subroutines
 # // ---------------

 (?(DEFINE)

      # core
      (?<core>
           (?>
                (?&content) 
             |  
                (?:                   # Start-Delimiter
                     [a-z] \w* \s* \(      # Function
                  |  \(                    # Or, a open paren
                )
                (?:
                     (?= . )
                     (?&core)              # Recurse core
                  |  
                )
                \)                    # End-Delimiter, close paren
           )+
      )

      # content 
      (?<content>
           (?>
                (?!
                     [a-z] \w* \s* \(
                  |  [()] 
                )
                . 
           )+
      )
 )
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 29 ) 
example( other(1), 123, [25])  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 7 ) 
example  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 8 , len 20 ) 
 other(1), 123, [25]  
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 4 -  NULL 

-----------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 30 , len 16 ) 
othermethod(456)  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 30 , len 11 ) 
othermethod  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 42 , len 3 ) 
456  
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 4 -  NULL
```

*For the html div* -

```
 # '~(?s)(?:<div>((?&core)|)</div>)(?(DEFINE)(?<core>(?>(?&content)|<div>(?:(?=.)(?&core)|)</div>)+)(?<content>(?>(?!</?div>).)+))~'

 (?xs-)
 (?:
      <div>                 # Start-Delimiter <div>
      (                     # (1), CORE
           (?&core) 
        |  
      )
      </div>                # End-Delimiter </div>
 )

 # ///////////////////////
 # // Subroutines
 # // ---------------

 (?(DEFINE)

      # core
      (?<core>
           (?>
                (?&content) 
             |  
                <div>                 # Start-Delimiter <div>
                (?:
                     (?= . )
                     (?&core)              # Recurse core
                  |  
                )
                </div>                # End-Delimiter  </div>
           )+
      )

      # content 
      (?<content>
           (?>
                (?! </?div> )
                . 
           )+
      )
 )
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 82 ) 
<div>
    <div>
        <div>12</div>
        <div>34</div>
    </div>
</div>  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 5 , len 71 ) 

    <div>
        <div>12</div>
        <div>34</div>
    </div>

 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 

---------------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 84 , len 13 ) 
<div>56</div>  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 89 , len 2 ) 
56  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL
```